# Difference between wt.t1 and wt in R - Biwavelet package

Tags: r, biwavelet

What is the difference between wt.t1 and wt in R - Biwavelet package

I am confused between the following two codes

plot(wt.t1())
plot(wt())

Is it related to lags? like the lag 1 and lag 2 in time series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wt()` is a function in the Biwavelet package, while `wt.t1()` is not. I guess you mixed it for an object. `

```
wt.t1 <- wt()
```

In that case, `wt.t1` is only an object that contains the result of the function.